# CaptureError {code: 20} while buiding in browser

Tags: cordova, browser, ionic2

I'm using MediaCapture pluggin for video recording. It is working fine with android, but in the browser its giving CaptureError {code: 20}.

I'm running in the browser as "ionic run browser"

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture/blob/master/www/CaptureError.js#L40) the error means Capture not supported

Comment: Is there any way to support capture in browser?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture#supported-platforms-3 video capture is not supported

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture#supported-platforms-2  image capture is supported..https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture#supported-platforms-1 audio capture is also not supported in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference with Ionic V4, try:

```
ionic cordova run browser
```